# How can I cancel other events when my UIPanGestureRecognizer occurs along side a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, event-handling, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer that I added to a UIScrollView, and when certain circumstances with the UIPanGestureRecognizer are met I want to cancel the touch/pan events from going to the UIScrollView, right now I have something like this:

```
-(void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if(/* some logic */) {
          [sender cancelsTouchesInView];
    }
}
```

however calling [sender cancelsTouchesInView] does not stop scrolling from occurring in my UIScrollView.

I come from a big JavaScript background and I tend to expect events to behave in the same way and I think it's my downfall that they don't. I'm finding it really difficult to understand how events are handled in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if(/* some logic */  && sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
          [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
   else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
          [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: While this works, I was hoping for a more general answer that would stop events everywhere else.